# Subquery returned more than 1 value n SQL Server

Tags: sql

I am running below query and getting this error.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Query :

```
select 
    pt.CategoryName,
    pt.AgentDepartmentName,
    pt.TicketsOpened,
    cast(round((pt.TicketsOpened / convert(decimal(16, 2), (select case when sum(pt.TicketsOpened)> 0 then sum(pt.TicketsOpened) else 1 end from @PhoneTempResults)))*100,2) as numeric(36,2))
from 
    @PhoneTempResults pt
group by 
    pt.CategoryName, pt.AgentDepartmentName, pt.TicketsOpened
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am very new to sql and not sure how to fix this.Please help

Comment: You may not need a sub-query and could use just `case when` portion.

Comment: Looks like the code inside of your cast expression is returning more than one value. Separate it out and try debugging from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a window function:

```
select pt.CategoryName, pt.AgentDepartmentName, pt.TicketsOpened,
       cast(round(pt.TicketsOpened * 100.0 / sum(sum(pt.TicketsOpened)) over (), 2
                 ) as numeric(36,2)
           )
from @PhoneTempResults pt
group by pt.CategoryName, pt.AgentDepartmentName, pt.TicketsOpened
```

Comment: Here I need to check the 0's also for pt.TicketsOpened in the denominator.If its morethan 0 I need to take sum(pt.TicketsOpened) else it should be 1